# URL redirection in mac osx yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, redirect

I need to redirect a particular url to my localhost in mac osx-yosemite. I'm able to do the port forwarding using the following.

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

But can't figure out how to make a particular URL to be redirected to my localhost. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your hosts file - should be at:

```
/private/etc/hosts
```

Add a new line

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

This will make requests for domain.com be sent to your mac. You may need to close and reopen your browser to flush any local DNS cache it may hold.